# A null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server URL, exception was ServerProtocolviolation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Currently using Visual Studio-2017 and installed Appium Webdriver.
While preparing the code for Windows Calculator getting below Error:

```
An exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://10.206.8.232:169/wd/hub/session. The status of the exception was ServerProtocolViolation, and the message was: The server committed a protocol violation.
```

At the line:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.245.12.81:139/wd/hub"), caps);
```

I expected to Open the Windows Calculator and to perform the action.